# how to convert a type" <class 'foldername.modulename.functionname'>" to dict in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and want to write a XML File using a dictionary value .

When I assign my dictionary to a variable and use dicttoxml as mentioned below, I am able to write a xml file  .

```
My_Dict = {'data': [{'entity_id': '123456',
           'layout': [{u'database': {u'id': abc
                                     u'name': u'aaa abc
                       u'section': {u'id': u'abc123',
                                    u'name': u'MYSTRING'},
                       u'seriesCode': u'SR11111',
                       u'table': {u'id': u'TB98765',
                                  u'name': u'STRING \u1111 STRING\u2000'},
                       u'topic': {u'id': u'TP890762',
                                  u'name': u'Zee-STRING(Name)'}}],
           'metadata': {'classification': ONE,
                        'country': {'id': 'YYY', 'name': 'ABC'},
                        'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 11, 02),
                        'frequency': {'id': 'YYYY', 'name': 'string'},
                        'id': 123456,
                        'indicator': one,
                        'key_series': one
                        'last_change': {'is_infinity': one
                                        'is_opposite': one
                                        'value': -87},
                        'last_update_time': datetime.datetime(2000, 05, 12, 10, 8, 46, tzinfo=tzutc()),
                        'last_value': 77777777,
                        'multiplier_code': 'OP',
                        'name': 'Abc Defg',
                        'new_series': one,
                        'number_of_observations': 19,
                        'period_end': 00,
                        'province': None,
                        'source': {'country_id': one,
                                   'id': 'YYY-ABC
                                   'name': 'ABC DEF IGK'},
                        'start_date': datetime.date(1983, 20, 05),
                        'status': {'id': 'K', 'name': 'Inactive'},
                        'unit': {'id': '200056', 'name': 'PQR pp'}},
           'subscribed': one,
           'time_points': one,
           'ui': one}

dicttoxml.dicttoxml( My_Dict , attr_type=False, root=True)
```

But the above dictionary values will be generated when I execute another SDKfile and its type is not dict. The type of a generated value is

`<class 'FileName.FolderName.Classname.FucntionName'>`

if I typecast my result to str and try to convert str -> dic

`xml_data = dicttoxml.dicttoxml( str(My_dict), attr_type=False, root=True )`

I am getting following error .

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    xml_data = dicttoxml.dicttoxml( str(xmltext), attr_type=False, root=True )

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dicttoxml.py", line 393, in dicttoxml
    convert(obj, ids, attr_type, item_func, cdata, parent=custom_root), 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dicttoxml.py", line 177, in convert
    return convert_kv(item_name, obj, attr_type, cdata)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dicttoxml.py", line 334, in convert_kv
    attrstring = make_attrstring(attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dicttoxml.py", line 117, in make_attrstring
    attrstring = ' '.join(['%s="%s"' % (k, v) for k, v in attr.items()])
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Please help me , how to resolve this error .

Comment: what does your  `__str__` method of class contains?

Comment: The class "Classname" does not contain __str__method. Please clarify if I misunderstood your question

Comment: Use this then get back to me i will be solving if you still doesn't understand it: https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for the help but I have analyzed my situation and I think I am getting this error because my string contains datetime function “last_update_time': datetime.datetime(2000, 05, 12, 10, 8, 46, tzinfo=tzutc())”. I tried to solve the situation by using ast.literal_eval, as I am new to python getting lot of errors. If I can convert this as a string or if I can format it to “%Y,%m,%d, %H,%M,%S'” format, I hope it will resolve my problem. 
 

Can you please guide me or help to resolve this issue.

Comment: use strftime https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: and check before converting what's the type of the object you are getting, i guess you are getting Boolean object instead of class object

Comment: Thanks for your help, I resolved my issue.